# yarn workspaces shared package does not load in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I am using yarn workspaces to maintain my monorepo with this structure:

```
root
|- package.json
|- packages
   | - frontend          -> create-react-app
       |- package.json
   | - shared            -> custom library
       |- package.json
   | - backend           -> nestjs
       |- package.json
```

My root `package.json`:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ]
}
```

`package.json` of each package:

```
  "name": "@app/<package_name>",
  "version": "1.2102.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "example",
  "repository": {
   ...
  },
  "scripts": {
   ...
  },
```

When I try to use my `shared` library in `frontend` package like so:
`import { something } from "@app/shared";`
I get this error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@app/shared' in '<path>\packages\frontend\src\<path>'
```

I tried to add dependency `"@app/shared": "1.2102.0"` into `packages/frontend/package.json`, but it was not helpful. Yarn does not spit any error or warnings.

It is caused by `create-react-app`? Is it supported? Or I am doing something wrong?

Also I need to point out that project is in pure JavaScript (not TypeScript). I have another TS monorepo also with `cra` and it works fine even without including my `shared` library into `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you add the package in the package.json dependencies where you want to use that other package.

also make sure you try re-running the project as hot eloading might not be enabled

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found out that this is due to `create-react-app` limitations.

CRA does not allow any imports from outside the `/src` folder.

So there is unfortunately no fix for this issue and it is the expected behaviour of CRA.

Comment: Consider adding some supporting references/links. That extra context could help future readers. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/33847070)